# how to convert a dictionary containing iterables as items to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary d

```
d=dict()
d['a']=2
d['b']=3
d['c']=list([1,5,7])
```

if I try to convert it using

```
 pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

then I get

```
df=
'a'     'b'     'c'
2       3        1 
2       3        5
2       3        7
```

while I wanted:

```
df=
'a'     'b'     'c'
2       3        [1,5,7]
```

how to obtain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T
```

Comment: nice and very simple

Comment: Excellent, feel free to accept so people know it works!

Comment: yes I will.can you add the tricky part: when does this not work?

Comment: If you have repeat indices, e.g. d['b'] = 3, then d['b'] = 4, this won't get picked up because dictionary keys are unique.